# Is There a way to use Zend Search Lucene in a way similar to Useing the WHERE LIKE sql in Databases?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

```
$select = $this->_db->select()->from($this->_name,array("id","fullname","username","email"))->where("fullname LIKE '$query%'");
```

I am using this SQL statement currently to power my Ajax auto suggest, if i type in "a" it gets me results starting with a.

I want to know if this can be accomplished my using Zend Lucene indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first stop should be the Zend Framework reference manual, and more specifically :
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html

So you can use * for wildcard searches just like you would use % in SQL (ie. when you provide part of a word).